# Can i make cname point to remote URL directory

Tags: dns, cname, nameservers, amazon-route53

I have the remote url like this

`http://www.abc.com/my data/files` and i want to make my subdomain point to

this like

media.mydomain.com to that so that if i have file like

`http://www.abc.com/my data/files/abc.pdf` then i can serve it via

`media.mydomain.com/abc.pdf`

Answer (score 1):

That cannot be done just with DNS records.

You can to point your subdomain to the same webserver and then use different **Name-based virtual host** settings for the subdomain, i.e. the webserver uses different configurations based on the hostname you actually use in your request even though the map to the same IP address in DNS.

If your webserver is Apache, you can read about Virtual Host setup at

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/